# How can I preserve order with an EnumMap in java

Tags: java

I have an EnumMap that I'm using and I will need to keep the order of the items that I'm passing in. I know that when using a HashMap, I can initialize a LinkedHashMap in order to preserve order like so:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> contentTypeToIdList = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

However, I'd like to use an EnumMap instead. How would I be able to do something like this:

```
EnumMap<ContentType, List<String>> contentTypeToIdList = new LinkedHashMap<ContentType, List<String>>();
```

Comment: Please explain why you insist on using EnumMap when a LinkedHashMap solves your problems.

Comment: You might have to invent your own wheel on this one. There is no `LinkedEnumMap` and the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) say that "Enum maps are maintained in the natural order of their keys (the order in which the enum constants are declared). This is reflected in the iterators returned by the collections views (keySet(), entrySet(), and values())."

Comment: Can you modify `ContentType`?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede you mean to except a String instead? I'd rather not since an EnumMap is better performance-wise. Plus, I'd also have to refactor a lot in order for that to work

Comment: @DanielD You said in comments that the consumer of the map is outside your control.  Do you control the class `ContentType`, or is that also a third party class?

Comment: @Matsemann I am working with some legacy code that requires I pass it an EnumMap rather than a generic Map. And I need to preserve order because it would change the logic in the calling function

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Yes, I can update the ContentType. What are you proposing?

Answer (score 5):

As the API tells us:

> Enum maps are maintained in the natural order of their keys (the order in which the enum constants are declared). This is reflected in the iterators returned by the collections views (keySet(), entrySet(), and values()).

This means it is internally sorted and simply not supposed to be ordered differently, e.g. insertion order as you need it.

Comment: I am trying to write a test for some legacy code that would only accept an EnumMap. The order of which I add elements to the map changes how I would be mocking another call

Comment: You're already using a mocking framework? It's the only possibility I can see at the moment...

Answer (score 3):

You really don't need an `EnumMap`.  You can get away with *just* using the `LinkedHashMap`, but you have to be mindful of what you're keying off of.

```
Map<ContentType, List<String>> contentTypeToIdList = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

This will:

- Use a `LinkedHashMap`
- Ensure insertion order relative to when the key (and its values) are added

Comment: I would if I could. I'm working with some legacy code that has to take in an EnumMap rather than a generic Map. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: It sounds then like you're stuck.  Not much else to say; you can't enforce order on something which has concretely defined its order.

Comment: @DanielD In that case your only hope is "extending" `EnumMap` with your own implementation that uses a `LinkedHashMap`. Essentially you're replacing the original `EnumMap` this way, so this is a horrible solution, but within the constraints you give, it's the only one.

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities:

- Use `LinkedHashMap` and [construct an `EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html#EnumMap(java.util.Map)) from it each time you need one.
- As biziclop suggested in a comment, extend `EnumMap`.
- I was going to suggest extending or modifying `ContentType` to contain mutable static ordering information, which would be horribly hacky but maybe okay for testing.  But I like the above two ideas better.

Comment: The first option won't work. The order in the `EnumMap` will change.